# Data ingestion using kafka from crawlers

Tags: python, apache-kafka, web-crawler, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to work with Kafka for data ingestion but being new to this, i am kind of pretty much confused.I have multiple  crawlers, who extract data for me from web platform. Now, the issue is i want to ingest that extract data to Hadoop using Kafka without any middle scripts/service file . Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you looked into using the Confluent HDFS Connector? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without any middle scripts/service file . Is it possible ?

Unfortunately, no.

You need *some service* that's writing into Kafka (your scraper). Whether you produce into Kafka HTTP links (then write an intermediate consumer/producer that generates the scraped results), or only produce the final scraped results, that's up to you.

You also need a *second service* consuming those topic(s) that writes to HDFS. This could be Kafka Connect (via Confluent's HDFS Connector library), or PySpark (code you'd have to write yourself), or other options that include "middle scripts/services".

If you'd like to combine both options, I would suggest taking a look at Apache Nifi or Streamsets, which can perform HTTP lookups, (X)HTML parsing, and Kafka+HDFS connectors, all configured via a centralized GUI. Note: I believe any Python code would have to be rewritten in a JVM language to support major custom parsing logic in this pipeline

Comment: Worth noting that if his goal was for the spark service to just take the kafka data stream and write it to HDFS, that would be a pretty simple spark app to write.

Comment: True, it's also possible to skip using Kafka as "a queue" entirely and scrape and write to HDFS all within a Spark executor

Comment: Yeah if kafka isn't actually adding any value to your architecture, it's better to not deal with it and write directly to where you want the data. My experience with kafka is that getting a cluster deployed with the right settings and maintaining it is not a small task. If you're already using AWS, there's Kinesis as a managed alternative, but it gets expensive at high volumes. IIRC they wanted around $45k a month to process 1M messages per second.

Comment: That's what I've heard. Luckily, I'm currently working with a very experienced operational Kafka team. Terraform, Ansible, and Splunk can go a long way

Comment: Thank you guys ! I appreciate your opinions.